# Unity. Stop app on android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Create empty project in unity. Compile it to APK. When try to start : "Unfortunately (app) has stopped"
 Device Filter : "FAT (ARMv7 + x86)"
Here is a logcat:

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
E/VoldConnector(  652): NDC Command {468 asec create smdl2tmp1 45 ext4    [scrubbed] 10005 1} took too long (8857ms)
E/VoldConnector(  652): NDC Command {470 asec finalize smdl2tmp1} took too long (669ms)
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
E/rsC++   (23278): RS Message thread exiting.
E/Finsky  (29234): [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bl.a(3): onConnectionFailed:      ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
E/        (23278): appName=com.android.launcher3, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
E/        (23278): 0
E/        (  652): Could not open '/data/data/hotplug/cmd'
E/        (  652): error : 2, No such file or directory
E/AuthorizationBluetoothService(  908): Proximity feature is not enabled.
E/AuthorizationBluetoothService(  908): Proximity feature is not enabled.
E/dalvikvm(30687): Could not find class 'android.telecom.TelecomManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.wearable.service.y.a
E/AuthorizationBluetoothService(  908): Proximity feature is not enabled.
E/dalvikvm(30621): Could not find class 'android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.lockbox.LockboxService.a
E/MDM     (  809): [52] b.run: Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}
E/MDM     (  809): [66] b.run: Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}
E/MDM     (  809): [66] b.run: Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}
E/CellLocation(  809): create GsmCellLocation
E/CellLocation(  809): create GsmCellLocation
E/CellLocation(  809): create GsmCellLocation
E/cutils-trace(30720): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
E/memtrack(30720): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
E/android.os.Debug(30720): failed to load memtrack module: -2
E/VoldConnector(  652): NDC Command {482 asec create smdl2tmp1 45 ext4 [scrubbed] 10005 1} took too long (8436ms)
E/VoldConnector(  652): NDC Command {484 asec finalize smdl2tmp1} took too long (2238ms)
E/        (  652): Could not open '/data/data/hotplug/cmd'
E/        (  652): error : 2, No such file or directory
E/installd(  154): prepare_ext cache dir /mnt/sdcard/dalvik-cache/ fail: File exists
E/installd(  154): cannot chmod '/mnt/sdcard/dalvik-cache/mnt@asec@com.a.b-1@pkg.apk@classes.dex' : Operation not permitted
E/jdwp    (30720): jdwp::setsockopt(SO_SNDTIMEO)
E/jdwp    (30720): jdwp::setsockopt(SO_RCVTIMEO)
E/Finsky  (29234): [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bl.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
E/AuthorizationBluetoothService(  908): Proximity feature is not enabled.
E/AuthorizationBluetoothService(  908): Proximity feature is not enabled.
E/dalvikvm(30869): Could not find class 'android.telecom.TelecomManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.wearable.service.y.a
E/MDM     (  809): [52] b.run: Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}
E/MDM     (  809): [52] b.run: Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}
```

Comment: What device are you running your apk on? are you using any of google service? read the logs carefully you would find answer. Others might now be able to help you as only you know what is in your project.

Comment: @UmairM Empty project. No Google service, no scripts, nothing. Device : Android 4.4.2 Fly FS403

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Pmi5s here is screen shoot